# Which condition is true? and why? in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Which condition is true?**

```
 1 == false 
 1 === false 
'1' == false
```

none of the above?

Comment: Have you tried running those in a JavaScript file and see what they return or log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript will automatically convert the Boolean into an integer and then attempt to compare the two sides.

For real equality, use the === operator.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it